# Windows Authentication on load balancer

Tags: iis, https, load-balancing, windows-authentication

What changes are required to `Enable Windows Authentication` on `load balancer` ?
I have two servers for the production website (`HTTPS`) on which I need to enable windows authentication.

Which places do I need to change and what changes to be done ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable the windows authentication on all the servers and disable the anonymous authentication.

Make sure the authentication setting on all the servers is the same.

[image]